# How to use contextual action mode with SherlockListFragment

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I want use a Contextual Action Bar (CAB) in my app but is not compatible with old versions of Android so I'm using this tutorial: http://www.miximum.fr/tutos/849-porting-the-contextual-anction-mode-for-pre-honeycomb-android-apps
My code is:

```
public class SongsFragment extends SherlockListFragment implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, OnLongClickListener{

...
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    activity = this.getActivity();
    ...
    mMode = null;
    mListView = getListView();
    mListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    mListView.setOnLongClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    SparseBooleanArray checked = mListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
    boolean hasCheckedElement = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < checked.size() && !hasCheckedElement; i++) {
        hasCheckedElement = checked.valueAt(i);
    }

    if (hasCheckedElement) {
        if (mMode == null) {
            mMode = activity.startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
        }
    } else {
        if (mMode != null) {
            mMode.finish();
        }
    }
    return false;
}

 private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // Create the menu from the xml file
        activity.getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cab_songs, menu);
        return true;
    }
    ...
```

I have errors in:

1. -"activity.startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);": The method startActionMode(ActionMode.Callback) in the type Activity is not
   applicable for the arguments (ActionMode.Callback)
2. -activity.getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cab_songs, menu);": The method getSupportMenuInflater() is undefined for the
   type FragmentActivity

Any idea? is there another solution for CAB using sherlock?

Comment: This is how I did it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737519/implementing-multi-selection-and-contextual-actionmode-in-actionbarsherlock/14737520#14737520

Answer (score 2):

Change your imports for `ActionMode` and `MenuInflater` to their ActionBarSherlock equivalents (`com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionMode` and `com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater`).

Answer (score 2):

I solved using:

```
getSherlockActivity().startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
...
mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cab_songs, menu);
```

Now, I want do an action when the user does a "click" and another action when the user does a "long click". I've "onItemLongClick" and "onListItemClick" but sometimes longClick is not called and when it is called if I release the "onListItemClick" is called. How can I do this actions?