# Using Android action bar share intent

Tags: android, android-menu, android-optionsmenu

I'm using a menu item on the action bar and I want to share my app by clicking the share icon. When I click the share icon it doesn't work. Also, I want to add text saying `"install this app"` when shared.

Here is my code:

```
private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainpage, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();

    return true;
}

private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    }
}
```

**Mainpage.xml menu:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Share"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_store"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
</menu>
```

Comment: So where are you calling `setShareIntent`? You need to call it at least once for the `ShareActionProvider` to be clickable.

Comment: sorry, i have no idea. do you have any suggestion on how to improve my code, all i want is get a clickable share icon on my action bar.

Comment: @user2598397 you have an example @ android-sdk/samples/android-17/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List16. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698596/checkable-relative-layout-as-item-in-multiselect-list/17698673#17698673 and this http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want a static share `Intent` (i.e., it never changes), then you update your `onCreateOptionsMenu` to be

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainpage, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
    // Create the share Intent
    String playStoreLink = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" +
        getPackageName();
    String yourShareText = "Install this app " + playStoreLink;
    Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
        .setType("text/plain").setText(yourShareText).getIntent();
    // Set the share Intent
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I see the dark share icon instead of the white one...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601329/how-to-make-the-share-action-icon-white-instead-of-gray

Comment: I am confused. You set the intent when the option menu is created. But if you use an action bar that happens very early. At a time when I don't yet have the data to share.

Comment: @Martin - yes, that's why I prefaced it with 'if you want a static share'. Otherwise just call `setShareIntent` with a new Intent whenever is appropriate for your app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now appropriate would be when the user clicks the share button ;-). I see how I manager that.

Comment: @Martin - actually there isn't a listener on when the ShareActionProvider is clicked AFAIK - you should set the intent as soon as you have the data needed.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the official tutorial here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionProvider

In the snappet you paste, you forget to call

```
mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
```

Comment: Upvoted. Downvoting without an explanation is a nasty habit, imho.