# How to make the Share action icon white instead of gray

Tags: android

My app has the `ShareAction` icon as displayed below. 
How I make it white instead of gray. It looks like it's disabled right now.

[image]

My XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

   <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
        android:title="Share"
        android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />

</menu>
```

`ic_action_share` is a white icon as shown below:

[image]

Comment: You are using icon `@drawable/ic_action_share` so you can just replace it by white one (paint it). Otherwise you can find other icons here: http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

Comment: I originally didn't have an icon but it showed gray by default. I added a white icon but it is still gray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `ic_action_share`  IS gray, well you have to make a white image

Comment: I originally didn't have an icon but it showed gray by default. Now I added a white but it still shows gray

Comment: verify the name of it, and the name you work with in xml, also, a clean might help

Comment: Verification is done. It's a white icon but still shows up as gray... hmmmmm

Comment: there must be some kind of mapping problem, your best solution is to import this icon into your project, to your drawable folder, and work with it

Comment: It was the Theme I was using and then customize the ActionBar. I accepted your answer because you helped :)