# How to add multiple activities under one onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, oncreate, oncreateoptionsmenu

I want to add multiple activities under one `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) in my android app, I have already added two activities and they are working fine but third activity isn't working, following is my code

```
onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public final boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_item_share:
            shareURL();
    }
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_item_refresh){
        mWebView.reload();
        return true;
    }
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.share_this_app)
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private void shareURL() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mWebView.getUrl());
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share This Website!"));
    shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
}


/** Returns a share intent */
private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "download the app");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT," play.google.com ");
    return intent;
}
```

menu_main.xml

```
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
    android:title="@string/share"
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/share"
    />

<item
    android:id="@id/menu_item_refresh"
    android:title="Refresh"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="@drawable/refresh"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/share_this_app"
    android:title="Share this app"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
```

From above, menu_item_share and menu_item_refresh is working, but Share this app isn't working.

Comment: There is no `return true;` for the last one.

Comment: Put all possibilities in that switch statement. Or use only ifs.

Comment: `I have already added two activities` ??? Activities? Nowhere i see an Activity.

Comment: `but Share this app isn't working.` Share this app ? Can't you be precise? And what is `not working`? What should happen that does not happen? You are only setting an intent. Nowhere you start an activity there.

Comment: @greenapps now i have added menu_main.xml to question as well, by share this app isn't working. i mean after clicking on share this app option it should be able to send my apps google play store link to other apps, but the share this app option isn't responding .

Comment: `it should be able to send my apps google play store link to other apps, ` Really? Why do you thinkk it would? You are only setting an intent. You are not starting it.

Comment: `mShareActionProvider`. You are not showing what that is and how it is instantiated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928709/using-android-action-bar-share-intent

Comment: `How to add multiple activities`. Pretty bad description of your problem.

Comment: @greenapps it worked, thank you very much.

Comment: @greenapps i quoted question like that because i wasn't aware about how to use single onCreate for multiple actions.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably your are missing a return true statement below this line **mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());**. You can simply follow a clean structure to achieve your task.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_item_share: {
        shareURL();
        break; //or, return true;
    }
    case R.id.menu_item_refresh: {
        mWebView.reload();
        break; //or, return true;
    }
    case R.id.share_this_app: {
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());
        break; //or, return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: not working, now its force closing the app after clicking on share this app, i have added both share intents in question, if you can have a look at it and let me know if there is something wrong with them.

Comment: you already have used what you need in shareURL() method. (1) create a method like 'shareURL()'. (2) follow: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html to share your app_playstore_url via other apps. (3) call the new method when you press on R.id.share_this_app

Comment: you can accept/upvote the answer if it was helpful. Your little inspiration encourages us to spend more time here :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think this would help...
You have written 
  **android:showAsAction="never"**.
So it would generate an error while putting an icon inside the menu icon(three dots at toolbar).
Hence put the value **"always"** or  **"ifRoom"** for this attribute.
Hope this would work  :-)