# Action bar share button not working after upload on playstore

Tags: android

App share button on action bar  is not working after i upload the app update on the play store as it works on the testing devices and also works on emulator.. ?
thank you in advance .

[Circled part is not working after uploading on play store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dEaD.png)

Activity:

```
public class RecommendetableActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    Intent ShareIntent;
    ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.recommended_table);
        ShareIntent = new Intent();
        ShareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        ShareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        ShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/............app name ");
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.close_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.backfadein, R.anim.backfadeout);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
        // Get its ShareActionProvider
        mShareActionProvider =  (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
        // Connect the dots: give the ShareActionProvider its Share Intent
        if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(ShareIntent);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.backfadein, R.anim.backfadeout);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.backfadein, R.anim.backfadeout);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

popup_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    />
</menu>
```

Comment: can you add the code, that you have implemented for share?

Comment: added @gopal_patil... reply soon ..

Comment: this seems to be the possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928709/using-android-action-bar-share-intent

Comment: it is working on emulator and other devices but not after uplaoding it on playstore.... @gopal_patil

Comment: is it for any specific device or API(os version)?

Comment: Bro but its working on emulator and other devices but not after i uploaaad it on play store .. @gopal_patil

Comment: min 16 sdk and max is 25   
playstore link is : "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=www.welkinfort.com.emfdetector"  
Check it out . @gopal_patil

Comment: "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=www.welkinfort.com.emfdetector"

Comment: EMF DETECTOR WELKINFORT@gopal_patil

Comment: this is strange, you have to look for an alternative.

Comment: anyone else have any solution... ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well once and after some digging inside the Logcat of Play store ready APK, I found the problem; it might apply to you as well.

The Issue was `NoClassDefFoundError` exception on `ShareActionProvider` !
Solution is to add this rule to your ProGuard file such as `proguard-rules.pro` and that's it!

> -keep class android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider { *; }