# listView count numbers of selected rows

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to find out the total number of selected rows in a customized list-view. If the number of items (rows) more than 2 then we cannot click the list-view again.Here I am using customized checklist(Multiple Choice)

Comment: What you have tried? Post some code.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698596/checkable-relative-layout-as-item-in-multiselect-list/17698673#17698673

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
          lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long   id) 
        {
        int len = lvMain.getCount();
        SparseBooleanArray checked = lvMain.getCheckedItemPositions();
        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++){
        if (checked.get(i)) {
            count++;


               /* do whatever you want with the checked item */
           }

        }
        if(count>2)
        {
            /* do whatever you want with the checked item count more than one x value*/
            lvMain.setSelected(false);
            count=1;
        }
    }       

});
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with `listView.getCheckedItemCount()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to count the total number of selected rows in multiple listView.

```
for(i=0; listCount; i++) {
    if(mListView.isItemChecked(i)){

    }
    else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Else, you could try to store your checkboxes and the other element displayed in a row (*I've used `TextView` in my example*) in a `HashMap` when overridden `getView` method get called and then count how many elements are checked iterating over the `Map` :

```
Iterator<Entry<TextView, CheckBox>> it = listCheck.entrySet().iterator();
    int i = 0;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Entry<TextView, CheckBox> entry = it.next();
        if (entry.getValue().isChecked()) 
                i++;
    }   
    return i;
```