# onClick listener not working on predefined listview layout?

Tags: android, listview, sms, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener

I'm using predefined listview layout to show all the native messaging sms into my application.Code i defined in onCreate method:

```
lvInb = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvInb);
    lvInb.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
    data = fetchInbox();
    if(data!=null)
    {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 , data);
        lvInb.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        lvInb.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

for fetchInbox() I've created another method:

```
    public ArrayList<String> fetchInbox()
{
     ArrayList<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
     Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
     Cursor cr = getContentResolver().query(uriSms, new String[]{"_id", "address", "date", "body"},null,null,null);
     cr.moveToFirst();
        while  (cr.moveToNext())
        {
             sms.add(cr.getString(1)+"\n"+cr.getString(3)+"\n");
        }
        cr.close();
        return sms;
    }
```

code to delete row item in listview is:

```
private void openDelete() {
     removeListViewItem();

}
public void removeListViewItem() {
    if(intListViewItemPosition != -1){
        lvInb.removeViewAt(intListViewItemPosition);
        adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        intListViewItemPosition = -1;
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "No item selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

code in activity:

```
ListView lvInb;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
int intListViewItemPosition = -1;
ArrayList<String> data;
```

Outside onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);
    CreateMenu (menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    MenuChoice(item);
    return true;
}


private void CreateMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuItem mnu1 = menu.add(0,0,0,"Delete");
    {
        mnu1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }}
private boolean MenuChoice(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 0:
        removeListViewItem();
        break;
}
    return false;
}
public void removeListViewItem() {
    intListViewItemPosition = lvInb.getSelectedItemPosition();
    if(intListViewItemPosition != -1){
        //lvInb.removeViewAt(intListViewItemPosition);
        data.remove(intListViewItemPosition);
        adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        intListViewItemPosition = -1;
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "No item selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

delete option i've provided in menu options. but when i select a row item and click on delete option it shows No item selected

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698596/checkable-relative-layout-as-item-in-multiselect-list

Comment: @vipul mittal intListViewItemPosition = lvInb.getSelectedItemPosition(); line 207

Comment: show me what value you are getting if you print this line lvInb.getSelectedItemPosition(), like sys.println(lvInb.getSelectedItemPosition());

Answer (score 0):

Hey in where you are assigning the selected Item position value into "intListViewItemPosition"

If not used please implement this in your listview OnItemClickListener,

```
intListViewItemPosition= listView.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

You are trying to remove the selected Item from the listview right ?? for that you have clicked your listview item from the lisview, so you need to implement onClickListener for your listview

your code should be like this,

```
 your_listView_name.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
           intListViewItemPosition= listView.getSelectedItemPosition();
        }
    });
```

thats it..

Comment: where i need to assign intlistViewItemPosition can you tell in brief as i'm new to android

Comment: I have updated my previous post please go through it

Comment: in removeListViewItem i need to put it or in onCreate

Comment: you add removeListViewItem() method ouside onCreate and call removeListViewItem() from the menu option Delete pressed

Comment: then you removed that item from the ArrayList or not? if not remove that item from the arraylist also.

Comment: NullPointer Showing in data.remove(intListViewItemPosition), what is data here? have you passed  data= fetchInbox();?

Comment: Yes i've passed it in onCreate method check my code
but now no errors is showing but after clicking delete it show no item selected

Comment: One fast hand idea is implement that delete action in the listview onclicklistener, if it works you go for further

Answer (score 0):

first thing call `fetchIndex` only once:

declare an `ArrayList` of string in activity:

```
ArrayList<String> data;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter
```

and in onCreate:

```
lvInb = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvInb);
    lvInb.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
    data= fetchInbox();
    if(data!=null)
    {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 , data);
        lvInb.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        lvInb.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

now change change `removeListViewItem` to:

```
public void removeListViewItem() {
    intListViewItemPosition= lvInb.getSelectedItemPosition();
    if(intListViewItemPosition != -1){
        //lvInb.removeViewAt(intListViewItemPosition);
        data.remove(intListViewItemPosition);
        adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        intListViewItemPosition = -1;
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "No item selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

also have class level variable for adapter so that you can access it in `removeListViewItem`.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
```

and in onCreate just say:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 , data);
```

If you declare it again in onCreate the class level one would be `null` and you might get null pointer when your `removeListViewItem` will get called.

Comment: intListViewItemPosition= listView.getSelectedItemPosition(); showing erroe "listView" not recognize so i used lvInb my listview but after selection when pressed on delete application crash

Comment: can you post the logcat?? have you made the changes I mentioned?

Comment: intListViewItemPosition = lvInb.getSelectedItemPosition(); line 207

Comment: your lvInb is null?? can you post your current code that you are using as well?

Comment: ListView lvInb; should be outside onCreate check that

Comment: where are you initializing lvInb??