# Increment counter on listview

Tags: android, android-listview, parse-platform

What I want is that I'm trying to increment a counter everytime a user clicks on a item in listview. However each time the counter gets incremented only for the user which created that particular item in the listview. Please help, I want to increment the counter on each of the listItem where user clicks. Thanks.

```
             listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent,
                final View view, final int position, final long id) {

            try {
                caseID = ((CaseModel) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position))
                        .getCaseId();
                caseTittle = ((CaseModel) parent.getAdapter().getItem(
                        position)).getTitle();
                caseDescription = ((CaseModel) parent.getAdapter().getItem(
                        position)).getDescription();
                caseCreator = ((CaseModel) parent.getAdapter().getItem(
                        position)).getNameofcreator();
                userId = ((CaseModel) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position))
                        .getUserId();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

            if (caseID != null) {
                Intent gotoDetail = new Intent(
                        DoxinetCaseListActivity.this,
                        DoxinetCaseDiscussionForum.class);
                gotoDetail.putExtra("caseId", caseID);
                gotoDetail.putExtra("caseTitle", caseTittle);
                gotoDetail.putExtra("caseDescription", caseDescription);
                gotoDetail.putExtra("nameCreator", caseCreator);
                gotoDetail.putExtra("userId", userId);
                gotoDetail.putExtra("readStatus", true);
                callToCaseStats();
                callToIncrementCounter();
                startActivity(gotoDetail);
            } else {
                return;
            }

        }
    });
```

Here is the method callToIncrementCounter();

```
    protected void callToIncrementCounter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("case");
    //query.whereEqualTo("objectId", caseID);
    try {
        ob = query.find();

        System.out.println("In counter userob" + ob);

        for (ParseObject ob1 : ob) {

            counter = Integer.parseInt(ob1.get("counter").toString());
            System.out.println("In counter " + counter);

            counter = counter + 1;
            ob1.put("counter", counter );
            ob1.saveInBackground();
            System.out.println("In counter " + counter);
        }
    }

    catch (Exception d) {
        System.out.println("In exception");
        d.getMessage();
    }

}
```

Comment: Looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698596/checkable-relative-layout-as-item-in-multiselect-list/17698673#17698673??

Comment: @Raghunandan I want to increase the counter everytime user clicks on a list item !!!

Comment: What do you want?  A counter per row or a counter in general?

Comment: @zozelfelfo a counter per row

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a Map and use the position in the ListView as a key. The value of the map will be the count for each row.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make a counter for each `item` in the `listView`, if I got it right, and that is what you meant, please find a solution for this situation.

You are using the **default adapter** for the `listView` while you should use a **custom adapter**.

Then you should fill the **adapter** with `list<Objects>`, this `Object` should contain `counter` and `item`.

And then on `onItemClick` method you should update the `counter` for **clicked item** and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` this method will update the `listview` to show the updated counter for each item.