# Android Contextual Action Bar API 8+

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, contextual-action-bar

I want to use `Contextual Action Bar` in my app which supports API 8+ for multiple selection in the `ListView`. 
I have read that `Contextual Action Bar` is supported on API 11+ and for older devices I should provide older `Floating Context Menu`.

Anyway I'm wondering if there isn't a newer solution, for example some supportlibrary v7 update supporting CAB or so.

I'm not using ActionBarSherlock and I don't want to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ActionBarActivity` from the v7 support library supports the Contextual Action Bar via the same APIs as the API 11+ Activity class. The only difference is that the support methods all have "support" in them and you need to use the `android.support.v7.view.ActionMode.Callback` class for callbacks instead of the non-support version.

This has been a part of the v7 support library since the `ActionBar` classes were added to support the Action Bar in reversion 18, released in July of 2013.

See:

- [`startSupportActionMode(ActionMode.Callback)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#startSupportActionMode%28android.support.v7.view.ActionMode.Callback%29)
- [`onSupportActionModeFinished(ActionMode)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#onSupportActionModeFinished(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode))
- [`onSupportActionModeStarted(ActionMode)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#onSupportActionModeStarted(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode))

Comment: Thank you. I just read about this and want to update my question. But I don't fully understand how can I set `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL` to select multiple items in the list? Is is even possible?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not believe there is a support equivalent of `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL` for the support library. [This answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10682119/1253844) has a workaround for this. Though the answer uses ActionBarSherlock, the same logic should be re-usable for the support library.

Comment: Ok, I followed this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/14737520/2633630 and change it to work it with support library.. Thank you for your advice